# What is __brkval for AVR, and where is it defined?

Tags: c, avr

I have seen the `freeMemory` function in https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvailableMemory , and it seems to use something called `__brkval`. However, I simply cannot find where is this macro or variable defined:

```
$ grep -ri brkval /c/arduino-1.8.8/ --include='*.c' --include='*.h'
/c/arduino-1.8.8/libraries/Robot_Control/src/Fat16util.h:  extern int* __brkval;
/c/arduino-1.8.8/libraries/Robot_Control/src/Fat16util.h:  if (reinterpret_cast<int>(__brkval) == 0) {
/c/arduino-1.8.8/libraries/Robot_Control/src/Fat16util.h:                  - reinterpret_cast<int>(__brkval);
/c/arduino-1.8.8/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFatUtil.h:  extern int* __brkval;
/c/arduino-1.8.8/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFatUtil.h:  if (reinterpret_cast<int>(__brkval) == 0) {
/c/arduino-1.8.8/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFatUtil.h:                  - reinterpret_cast<int>(__brkval);

$ grep -ri brkval /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/ --include='*.c' --include='*.h'
# nothing

$ grep -ri brkval /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Atmel/Studio/ --include='*.c' --include='*.h'
# nothing

$ grep -ri brkval /c/cvavr/ --include='*.c'
# nothing
```

That is, only Arduino IDE has some references to it, but only as `extern int*` reference, it does not have a definition.

Closest I came to some sort of a verbose explanation is from https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/blob/master/src/FreeStack.h :

```
/** boundary between stack and heap. */
extern char *__brkval;
```

... but again, no definition.

So where is this variable or macro defined?

---

EDIT: as per comments, searching through all files:

```
$ grep -ri brkval /c/cvavr/
# nothing

$ grep -ri brkval /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Atmel/Studio/
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/avr25/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/avr25/tiny-stack/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/avr3/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/avr31/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/avr35/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/avr4/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/avr5/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/avr51/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/avr6/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/avrtiny/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/avrxmega2/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/avrxmega3/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/avrxmega3/short-calls/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/avrxmega4/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/avrxmega5/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/avrxmega6/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/avrxmega7/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/avr/lib/tiny-stack/libc.a matches
/c/Program Files (x86)/Atmel/Studio/7.0/toolchain/avr8/avr8-gnu-toolchain/doc/avr-libc/avr-libc-user-manual/stdlib__private_8h_source.html:<a name="l00045"></a>00045 <span class="keyword">extern</span> <span class="keywordtype">char</span> *__brkval;      <span class="comment">/* first location not yet allocated */</span>

$ grep -ri brkval /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/
Binary file /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/avr/lib/avr25/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/avr/lib/avr25/tiny-stack/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/avr/lib/avr3/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/avr/lib/avr31/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/avr/lib/avr35/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/avr/lib/avr4/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/avr/lib/avr5/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/avr/lib/avr51/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/avr/lib/avr6/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/avr/lib/avrtiny/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/avr/lib/avrxmega2/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/avr/lib/avrxmega4/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/avr/lib/avrxmega5/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/avr/lib/avrxmega6/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/avr/lib/avrxmega7/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/avr/lib/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/avr-gcc-8.2.0-x64-mingw/avr/lib/tiny-stack/libc.a matches

$ grep -ri brkval /c/arduino-1.8.8/
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avr25/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avr25/tiny-stack/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avr3/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avr31/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avr35/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avr4/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avr5/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avr51/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avr6/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avrtiny/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avrxmega2/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avrxmega3/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avrxmega3/short-calls/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avrxmega4/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avrxmega5/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avrxmega6/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avrxmega7/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/libc.a matches
Binary file /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/tiny-stack/libc.a matches
/c/arduino-1.8.8/libraries/Robot_Control/src/Fat16util.h:  extern int* __brkval;
/c/arduino-1.8.8/libraries/Robot_Control/src/Fat16util.h:  if (reinterpret_cast<int>(__brkval) == 0) {
/c/arduino-1.8.8/libraries/Robot_Control/src/Fat16util.h:                  - reinterpret_cast<int>(__brkval);
/c/arduino-1.8.8/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFatUtil.h:  extern int* __brkval;
/c/arduino-1.8.8/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFatUtil.h:  if (reinterpret_cast<int>(__brkval) == 0) {
/c/arduino-1.8.8/libraries/SD/src/utility/SdFatUtil.h:                  - reinterpret_cast<int>(__brkval);
```

Comment: If you search *all* the files, specifically any linker script files, does the symbol turn up then?

Comment: I have seen this symbol also in other environments. It is (as said) the boundary between stack and heap: stack can't grow below this value, heap can't go up above this value. The run-time system may adapt this. So if more stack is needed, the heap can be asked if it has memory available and vice versa, upon which the value can be adjusted. Upon linking (or loading), the linker (or loader) initializes this value to a "reasonble" value for both, or the compiler has added directives to calculate the break value.

Comment: Many thanks, @Someprogrammerdude - did the search through all files (see edit), and it mostly comes up with `libc.a`, which I guess is a static library; should I be able to "read" that variable with `nm` or `readelf`?

Comment: Thanks @PaulOgilvie - appreciate those details! All I was aware of, is that this is related to GCC, and related to stack/heap - and I wanted to use it in CodeVisionAVR code, but it has absolutely no reference to `brkval`, so I thought I'd see how GCC defines it - but while I can see it is in `libc.a`, I'm none the wiser on how I could it is defined (so I could maybe implement something similar in CodeVisionAVR)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many others with the same question.  And as is pointed out, in simplest terms it is used to mark the boundary between stack and heap memory.  Here are some related discussions with content that includes `__brkval`:

- *[Arduino: Question about memory allocation analysis](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/52921/question-about-memory-allocation-analysis?rq=1)*.
- *[Free Memory Questions, Arduino](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=50135.0)*.
- *[Arduino:You know you have a memory problem when...](https://learn.adafruit.com/memories-of-an-arduino?view=all)*.
- *[AVRGCC: Monitoring stack usage](https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/soft-c-avrgcc-monitoring-stack-usage?page=all)*.
- *[Arduino Playground: CorruptArrayVariablesAndMemory](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/CorruptArrayVariablesAndMemory)*.

The final link addresses your main question, at least for Arduino environments:

> with the memory profiler function added (note that it uses freeMemory via ***MemoryFree.h***, which is also given in the thread above), and starting array size of 100 elements (400 bytes):

```
// minitest.pde

static unsigned long mydata_count;

static const long SERSPEED=115200;
static const int SIZE=100;
static const char RSTSTR[] = "RESET!!";

static unsigned long mydata[SIZE];

#include <MemoryFree.h>

extern unsigned int __data_start;
extern unsigned int __data_end;
extern unsigned int __bss_start;
extern unsigned int __bss_end;
extern unsigned int __heap_start;
//extern void *__malloc_heap_start; --> apparently already declared as char*
//extern void *__malloc_margin; --> apparently already declared as a size_t
extern void *__brkval;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, @ryyker - I guess what was confusing me, is how come it is not defined in any source file, and yet can be used as `extern`. Closest I came in the meantime is with: `$ /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr-objdump.exe -tT /c/arduino-1.8.8/hardware/tools/avr/avr/lib/avrxmega2/libc.a 2>/dev/null | grep -i brkval # =>
00000002       O *COM*  00000001 __brkval
00000000         *UND*  00000000 __brkval` ... so maybe during the compilation step, the compiler inserts this var at the "right place", so that its address represents the boundary?!

Comment: @sdbbs - One possible reason that you are not seeing it in the source files you have access to, is that the extern scope modifier is often declared in some .h file, defined in only 1 .c file then, as long as all of the other .c files in use have visibility of the .h file, they do not need to also include the definition. The definition then may be in a location that has not been made available? (i.e. rolled into one of the environment's exe or shared library files.?)

Comment: @sdbbs -  Take a look at the _Memory info from running Arduino_ section in the Arduino playground link above.  It has some interesting usage sections that may shed some light...

Comment: More likely the compiler or linker _creates_ these variables. The address of the variables are the start/end of the respective segment. Actually, the variables don't need to exist at all, as long as their sizes are in the executable so the loader can place/create the segments in memory.